# How to show endpoint documentation when my method inherits a base controller

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have multiple classes (more than 100) which inherit from my base class BaseController. All my classes are their logics and models but format's response (200, 404, 500, ...) are always the same.

But when I inherit from my base class, in my swagger documentation I see my endpoints but the details of the response are not there. How can I do this?

```c
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController() {}

    [Produces("application/json")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    protected async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        return await base.Get(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that this goes beyond swashbuckle... In your code you are hiding the get from the base, so all those annotations wont show... I don't think there is anyway to inherit those ___ You could try with an `IDocumentFilter` to apply those "always the same" items in one location

Comment: @sorcer1 did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, i think it's not possible ! :(

Answer (score 0):

As @Helder Sepulveda Said, this goes beyond swashbuckle.
I Think you can use `IActionModelConvention` to simulate inherit the action attributes.
Use `Action.Filters` like this

```
public class ActionMethodConvention : IActionModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ActionModel action)
    {
        var actonBaseResponses = new List<SwaggerResponseAttribute>();//some code to get baseAction reflections
        foreach (var attr in actonBaseResponses)
        {
            action.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(actonBaseResponses.StatusCode));
        }
}
```